# Why does hasNext() wait for input?

Tags: java, debugging, input, logic, java.util.scanner

In this simple code, I'm checking if a Scanner has something in the input buffer or not. So I used hasNext() to check whether it has something or not. But instead of returning "false" (in this case), it waits for input.
I can't understand why. It's a simple logic code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(in.hasNext()) System.out.println("It has next");
        else System.out.println("It doesn't have next");
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code, `in` is a `Scanner` Object that wraps `System.in`. System.in gets data from the system console. Theoretically, there is no limit to the number of fields or lines the user could type using the console. There is always the potential for more data. So, `in.hasNext()`, `in.next()`, and so on wait for I/O.  Contrast where `Scanner` Object wraps a file, which does have a definite end. So, when a `Scanner` Object is used to read a file serially, `~.hasNext()` will eventually return `false`.

Comment: You wouldn't want if differently. If 'hasNext' said there was no next when there was nothing to be read right now, then you're forced to type faster than the computer can compute.  In your example code, after starting Java, you've got to have typed an integer before the main routine gets to its second line. I wouldn't bet money on your typing speed.

Comment: @dilettante You could *theoretically* design the class so `hasNext()` checks the current buffer and `next()` waits for input.

Comment: Well yea ... but that would be difficult to implement reliably given the specified semantics of `InputStream.available()` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--)).  Then there is the problem that the only way to reliably detect EOF would be to call `next()` and catch the exception. It would be a bad idea to try that ... IMO.

Comment: @shmosel - 'the current buffer' is likely in the terminal driver until end-of-line is typed, outside of the JVM's sight.